# How to justify (not center) text in Gmail?

Tags: email, gmail, text-formatting

Currently I'm presented with 3 text alignment options in the dropdown of my desktop Chrome Gmail editor: left, center, right **but not** justify. Yet justify is the preferred way for many publishers, and I think it's often the best looking for emails, so I'd be glad to know with my favorite email app, thanks.

Edit/explanations: my question has been "associated" (ie, hidden) with another of someone who didn't find the relevant tool menu, yet **I did find mine** (the **align dropdown** menu) and, as i said, as well as the (only 3, should be 4) options presented, **but** I didn't find the one to **justify** (**not just center**) an email, and I don't know what I can change in my original question to make it clearer ok thanks.

Edit 2: I **already** found that formatting options toolbar

[image: toolbar]

But **not** the option "justify" text (center text **isn't** what I need)

[image: dropdown with only 3 options]

Sorry but I don't get in what way the thread in which you merged/hidden my question answers it.

PS: Also maybe exists a way to justify text even though without that toolbar...